# Color Splash Screen Root Cause

Tags: boot-issues

An rPi-3 is:

- powered by 2A 5V power source \ several USB cables tested
- outfitted with OSMC_TGT_rbp2_20170210.img.gz

[image]

Does the splash screen indicate:

1. A power issue (cable / Amperes) ?
2. Hardware failure (board must be replaced)?
3. Flashcard issue (defective flashcard or software flashing / selection  issue)?

Comment: Usually this indicates the last point. But it does not neccesarily mean that the microSD card is defective. It might be that you missed a step in the process to flash the card. Which OS have you used? Which program have you used for flashing? Did you uncompress the image prior to flashing?

Comment: Probably the image is not compatible with your Pi.